# DataSource image becomes corrupted when sending a string in inline javax.mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send **inline imag**e in a mail through **java**.I have **byte array** so I converted byte array to **string** using below function.

```
 public static String getImgString(byte[] fileImg) throws IOException {
    String imageString = new String(fileImg,"UTF-8");
    return imageString;
}
```

I got an string and this string I verified through converter it displayed and image which I used.

Now I attached my image to body of mail with below code.

```
byte[] arr = getImageFileBytes(); // I got byte[] from this function
DataSource dataSourceImage = new ByteArrayDataSource(getImgString(arr),"image/png"");

MimeBodyPart imageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
imageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSourceImage));
```

I am receiving email as below.

I think there is some format I am missing in DataSource conversion or I need to add extra 
      **data:image/png;base64** to image string??

What changes I need to do to get an image that I have in String.

*Thanks in advance.*

[image]

Comment: All images need to be converted to base64, and then unconverted upon receipt to be sent in an email.

Comment: Never, ever use a String to store bytes.  That works in C, but not in Java.  Converting a byte array to a string will *corrupt* the bytes.  Why even bother?  Why not just do `new ByteArrayDataSource(arr, "image/png")`?

Comment: I tried with arr also I am getting the same.

Comment: Frank Mancini you mean to convert byte[] to base64 string and then?

Answer (score 2):

If your image data is actually in a file, you should use the [attachFile](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method:

```
MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp.attachFile("file.png", "image/png", "base64");
```

If you only have the image data in memory, you need to do something like this:

```
MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
ByteArrayDataSource bds = new ByteArrayDataSource(getImageFileBytes(), "image/png");
mbp.setContent(new DataHandler(bds));
```

Of course, if you're referencing this image from a separate html part, you'll want to make sure both are wrapped in a multipart/related part.

More information is in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr).

Comment: setContent is accepting only string right so i used mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bds)) but i facing same issue.

Comment: setContent accepts Object; read the javadocs.  If you're using the code I posted above and are "facing the same issue", then update your post with the latest code from your application.  Include the raw MIME content of the message you're sending, which you can get using "view source" or something similar in your email reader application.

Comment: You do not need to base64 encode anything; JavaMail will do that for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for help.